# Is there a quick and easy way to inspect DVD subtitles?

Tags: dvd, subtitles, ripping, matroska, handbrake

I'm looking for an easy and if possible quick way to inspect DVD subtitles, to determine their properties.

I am ripping some of my movies in `.mkv` format, using Handbrake for linux, and I'm having an hard time trying to determine which ones should I use.

In example, my DVD of "Star Trek: The motion picure" has audio in four languages and main subtitles in nine. Plus, there are some additional subs for specials (director's commentary and so on) and some more forced subs that contains only translations of scenes where a foreign (alien in this case) tongue is spoken.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, tracks from 1 to 9 are the main generic subtitles, tracks 10-17 are two different sets of commentary in the four main DVD languages, and tracks 18-21 are the ones used to dub foreign speech. Of course I get the same ones inside Handbrake.

In order to determine the content of the subs, I had to open VLC and try each one of them while playing the movie, to see which ones I need to keep during the conversion with Handbrake (namely, the generic and the forced ones, both in english and in italian).
But this is not very handy, especially because, AFAIK, not all DVDs store them separately like in this case; I have read that some keep the forced subs inside the same track of the general ones, and that those are marked in a way that the player can understand and only show them when required, without having to keep them on for all the duration of the movie,

Is there some way or some tool that can give me more informations about subtitles (i.e. main, commentary, forced dub, if it contains both general and forced, and so on) apart of their language? If possible under Linux, but I can also use Windows if needed.

Also, when inside Handbrake, to include the subs that I need (both normal and forced in english and italian), I have chosen these settings:

[image]

7 and 2 are the main ones, while 21 and 18 the forced ones; since I have separated tracks for forced subs, I still need to check the "forced only" box?

If both the general and forced subs were in a  single track, in order to have them both separately, should I insert the said track twice, and marking one as "forced only", or I can safely select it only once, and the special forced marks will be understood after the conversion as well?

Comment: I realized that maybe this question, despite relating to the same problem, could be splitted in two separate parts, one dealing with subtitles inspection tools and another with handbrake settings. If this is the case, let me know and I'll do it.

Comment: Try looking into MKVToolNix: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MKVtoolnix .. it has a MKV info tool to look into the contents of MKV files.. also MKVinfo: https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvinfo.html .. and this: http://www.videohelp.com/tools?toolsearch=mkv&submit=Search&portable=&s=&orderby=Name&hits=50